# Center the newly created text in GIMP?

Tags: gimp

After creating some text, how can I center it? I'm not talking about the text alignment inside the text box.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use the *Alignment Tool* (shortcut key <kbd>q</kbd>):

[image]

- Select the text,
- Then choose the element which will be used for positioning (e.g., *Image*),
- Click on the horizontal and vertical center align buttons (second column in the first set of buttons):

Comment: I pressed the 'q' key and nothing happened.

Comment: I couldn't find the "Align" options. Needed to go to Window -> Dockable Windows -> Tool Options. Documented here: https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-align.html

Comment: Doesn't work for me alignment buttons are grayed out.

Comment: This only allows to align the whole block. To center the text inside the block another solution is needed: https://askubuntu.com/questions/575079/centre-left-and-right-align-text-in-gimp
Anyways the key is to keep the Tool Options window opened ("Windows" ▶ "Dockable Dialogues" ▶ "Tool Options" ) and use Text or Alignment tool options.

Comment: @arp IME you'll have to select (click on) the text/object before the buttons will be not grayed-out.

Comment: I had to select `Image` in `Relative to` drop down menu. I tried Selection and Active Layer, but Image (like in the screenshot) did it.

Answer (score 4):

I've found solution:

1. On the empty art-board type text
2. Chose Alignment tool
3. Select text object pressing on it by left mouse key you'll see mini squares on the corners of selection
4. Use Alignment tool instruments to align text to art-board

[image: screenshot of GIMP]

I spent many time and realized that i missed 3-rd step. Select text object by clicking mouse, very important step. For me, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> or other selections didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually dead simple but even simpler to miss! All you have to do is click the [Align tool](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-align.html), then click the Layer over on the right side of your screen then go back to the lower left and click and an alignment button and hey presto. It works. Drove me mad for hours!

Answer (score 2):

For some reason none of the answers here worked for me, however, [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/GIMP/comments/49w7lw/is_there_a_way_to_center_a_selection_on_an_image/d0vr5jd?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) answer from reddit did!

> Create a vertical guide: Image - Guides - New Guide (by percent). Type in 50 percent.
>
> Then when you move the selection its center will automatically snap to guide.
>
> Add both vertical and horizontal guide if you want to center horizontally too.

By using the move tool and select the `move active layer` to move the text layer.

Comment: You don't even need the Move tool. While still in the Text tool, depress `Alt`+`Ctrl` and drag the text. Otherwise yes, the Align tool is often overkill.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. Tool is still broken in 2022