# Centre, left and right align text in GIMP

Tags: gimp, text-editor, design

I am running GIMP 2.8. And I was wondering if there is any way of left aligning, right aligning, or centring text in GIMP? As this would be something very useful and is included in most other programs.

[image: Text Aligning Standard Preferences]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Text alignment can be set in the "Tool Box" for the text tool:

[image: text align]

Comment: Open the shown "tool dialog" with the menu "Windows" ▶ "Dockable Dialogues" ▶ "Tool Options"

Comment: When select "Tool Options", nothing happens.  Any idea why?  Where it is hidden?  I am using the tool on mac.

Comment: @BTRNaidu: sorry, no idea about Mac... in Windows it is below the Color space too.

Answer (score 0):

Just hit the same thing in 2.10. Launched GIMP probably first time in months, tried adding text and the alignment controls just weren't there!

What helped was clicking the corner of the Tool Options window and resetting them, and the alignment control magically appeared.

No idea how to reproduce so won't file a bug but I hope this helps someone.

[image: click in the corner]
[image: reset]